# SQL Server - Cursor Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I am declaring a dynamic cursor due to a nesting of the stored procedure based on a parent-child relationship of the data that can go multiple levels and vary daily when processed.  The stored procedure works for the parent call, however the process of this procedure for child data causes a message stating that the "Cursor is not open."  This message occurs on the Fetch which is immediately after checking to be sure the cursor is open.

```
DECLARE @OutCur CURSOR; 
DECLARE @curName as NVARCHAR(MAX);
...
SET @curName = LEFT(replace(replace(CONVERT (time, GETDATE()),':',''),'.',''),8);
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT a.myfields FROM mytable a;            
SET @sqlCommand = 'SET @cursor' + @curName + ' = CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR ' + @sqlCommand + ' OPEN @cursor' + @curName + ';'

SET @curName = '@cursor' + @curName + ' cursor output';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlCommand,@curName,@OutCur output
IF CURSOR_STATUS('global','@OutCur')=-1
    OPEN @OutCur;
FETCH NEXT FROM @OutCur INTO @name,@type
```

Thanks in advance for the input.

Comment: Elaborate what are "routines" and how they communicate. Is your cursor declared in nested process?

Comment: Do you really need a cursor? Most of the time people use cursors when they shouldn't be because they are not familiar with how to do the same thing in a set based operation. Perhaps if you can share your actual logic we can get rid of the cursor entirely.

Comment: @SeanLange Do you have a default cut/paste response for this scenario? ;)

Comment: What if you are getting a value other than -1/0/1 back from CURSOR_STATUS check? Try printing CURSOR_STATUS to make sure.

Comment: @Lankymart I should. More often than not once the details come out the cursor is not needed.

Comment: Added to the code block and updated the description.  I have made efforts to avoid the cursor, but due to time pressures and complexity of the data, I've used the cursor for now and will attempt to go back and eliminate it.

Comment: With the most recent edit this is even more suspect to needing a rewrite. Why do you need to check the status of the cursor? You just declared it so it can't be in any other state right? Just open it and move forward.

Comment: The cursor check was done because of messages stating that the cursor is already open.   This all started because I wasn't able to use an INSERT EXEC to my table.

Comment: Well let's see if we can fix the problem instead of problems created by adding new code. Can you post the actual code you are running?

Comment: do you have `close @OutCur` and `deallocate @OutCur` inside your loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you uncomment close+deallocate - script works fine:

```
GO

DECLARE @OutCur CURSOR; 
DECLARE @curName as NVARCHAR(MAX), @sqlCommand nvarchar(max), @name varchar(100), @type varchar(100)
declare @i int = 0

while @i < 5
begin

  SET @curName = LEFT(replace(replace(CONVERT (time, GETDATE()),':',''),'.',''),8);
  SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ''111'' as name, ''cc'' as type; '
  SET @sqlCommand = 'SET @cursor' + @curName + ' = CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR ' + @sqlCommand + ' OPEN @cursor' + @curName + ';'

  SET @curName = '@cursor' + @curName + ' cursor output';

  EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sqlCommand,@curName,@OutCur output

  FETCH NEXT FROM @OutCur INTO @name,@type
  select @name, @type

  --close @OutCur
  --deallocate @OutCur

  set @i += 1
end
GO
```

Comment: Since cursor's aren't the desired method and the headache, i've gone another route with a # temp table.  Thanks all